# Is it worth getting photoshop if I'm not using it for photos?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it worth to get photoshop if I’m not using it for photos or photography? I might instead use it for cartoons, images, ui design, illustrations and other graphics but not photos nor photography.

Thanks.

Comment: What would you be using it for?

Comment: We can't decide for you whether something is worth it or not. That's entirely up to you.

Comment: Hi Joana, you need to frame your question so that it will be answerable and useful for others. You might be able to get an answer if you are specific about what you wish to accomplish with Photoshop. That won't be the case if you tell us what you don't want to use it for.

Comment: This is kind of like asking "Is it worth getting a toaster oven if I don't make toast?" -- There are uses beyond what a name may imply. Whether other uses would be beneficial to *you* no one here would know.

Comment: @Scott yes, its great for annealing.

Comment: @Scott - yeah hard to answer, but this is likely someone who is probably a raw beginner, so worthy of an answer I think, even though we can't possibly know what the OP is expecting from Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer, because only you really know what you need, but I'll give it a go.

There are better tools for UI design - such as Adobe XD (which is free), Figma, SketchApp (Mac only), etc. These kinds of software are specially designed for creating user interfaces. They're also much simpler than Photoshop, and are vector based rather than raster based.

Sure you can paint and draw with Photoshop and many people do use it for that, but it was primarily designed for photo editing - at the pixel level, especially useful for photo manipulation and so on. So, it might be overkill for what you want. Only you can decide really. I believe Adobe offers a 7 day trial, so you could try it out first and see what you think.

Maybe also have a look at Krita which is free and open source. It's probably just as good as PS for digital painting/drawing and it was actually designed for that purpose. It can also be used professionally as it has support for CMYK colour which is needed for print.

As for graphics like logos, better to use a vector image editor like Illustrator, Inkscape (free) or CorelDraw, Affinity Designer, etc.

It's important to know what Photoshop and other similar raster image editors are, and how they differ from vector software, what they are good for, and what they aren't so good for.  For graphics generally, designers often need vector images for things like print or for SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) on the web. Photoshop is raster based, so essentially painting with pixels.

There's a nice basic explanation of [Raster vs Vector graphics here](https://vector-conversions.com/vectorizing/raster_vs_vector.html) - I have no affiliation with this website or the author of the article.

Raster software is good for painting/drawing when you need painterly or sketchy effects, or blurs, smudges, gradients, like when trying to simulate natural media such as paint, brushes, pencils, etc.

Vector software is generally better for when you need geometric designs, beautiful curves, sharp edged shapes for logos or graphics, or for things like line art, and for type/font design.

Comment: There's also the amazing [Studio Artist](https://synthetik.com) which is vector-based painting + lots more madness.

Comment: @Tetsujin sure, And I've heard lots of good things about Corel Painter, a bit expensive though.  There are tons and tons of options out there for digital art.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop is not primarily a tool for photographers. There are better tools for that. It is a tool for people who want to prepare print publications. In fact if you are looking for a tool for any specific need that is not print preparation then theres most likely a better tool for what you are doing.

However, all these specialized tools are, well specialized. Photoshop is a adequate tool for nearly any task outside the area where its a king, print preparation, adobe suite compatibility and PDF support. In a way photoshop is a bit like Excel in this regard. You can do nearly anything with it, even things that you probably shouldn't.

I would say that there is not much point in getting just photoshop. If you can not atleast get the suite of illustrator, indesign, photoshop then its not really worth it. But theres no way we can say if you should get photoshop. Its like asking "should I get a piercing" with the info you have given us impossible to say.

Comment: Conversely, I've been using Photoshop since version 1 when it was Mac only - probably 25 or so years ago. I've never needed Illustrator or Indesign. Horses for courses, which is why I flagged this as opinion-based. We cannot decide for the OP what's "worth it".

Comment: Agreed - Photoshop for photographers is probably overkill too. As a keen amateur photographer, I've found Adobe Lightroom far more useful.  But when you need to bend reality however, Photoshop comes into its own.

Comment: @Tetsujin you probably dont "need" photoshop either, your just using it because of habit. Anyway i said we can not answer this question.